# Angular mat-list-item button in one line with text

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to change my icon to a button to use it as copy to clipboard method. But when I do it, the button moves to the right side. Only when I try a  around the text it works but of course the formatting is broken.

```
<mat-list>
        <h3 matSubheader>Persönliche Daten</h3>
        <mat-list-item>
          <button mat-icon-button ngxClipboard [cbContent]="firstname">
            <mat-icon  matListAvatar>account_box</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <h4 matLine>{{firstname}}</h4>
          <p matLine>Vorname</p>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider [inset]="true"></mat-divider>
        <mat-list-item>
          <mat-icon matListAvatar>description</mat-icon>
          <h4 matLine>{{lastname}}</h4>
          <p matLine>Nachname</p>
        </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

My CSS:

```
mat-list-item mat-icon[matListAvatar], .mat-list-item-content mat-icon[matListAvatar] {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

mat-list-item mat-icon[matListAvatar], .mat-list-item-content mat-icon[matListAvatar] {
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

/deep/ .mat-list-item-content {
    padding: 0!important;
}

/deep/ .mat-list-base .mat-subheader {
    padding: 0!important;
}

p {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
}
```

[image: Here you can see what's happening]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using the (click) property

You can just make the icon behave like a button.

Add a `(click)` property to it and call the function you want!

```
<mat-icon (click)="myFunction($event)" matListAvatar>account_box</mat-icon>
```

Then you can add some :hover css to it to make it feel like a button.

---

## Using HTML/CSS

You can place any content next to the button in a wrapper, you can customize this one in the css to behave differently if needed (if you end up adding more data to display you might have to play around with the flex properties, margin... or you might need to have nested wrappers, etc...)

```
<button mat-icon-button > 
  <mat-icon matListAvatar>account_box</mat-icon> 
</button> 

<div class="test-wrapper"> 
  <h4 matLine>{{firstname}}</h4> 
  <p matLine> Vorname</p> 
</div>
```

with this css:

```
.test-wrapper{ 
    padding-right: 0; 
    padding-left: 16px; 
    width: 100%; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
}
 
.test-wrapper > *{ 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to let a simple icon act like a button. It should be obvious for the user that this is clickable and has an effect.

Comment: Well you said you wanted to change the icon to a button. If you add the `(click)`property, it'll call whatever function once the icon is clicked. You don't have to do anything else. 

And to make it obvious that it's clickable, you can have some css so it becomes darker on hover. I'm not sure what the problem is. Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: The problem is that there is no function to call with `(click)`. So that won't really work. The library works different.

Comment: Gotcha, although I'm sure there's a way to copy to clipborad writing your own function, using the library is probably more logical. I'll have a look at it myself and edit this if I find anything

Comment: Yes I know I also wanted to create my own function but then my mind changed because I think I will use it also at different components.

Comment: Try removing the `matLine` from : ```<h4 matLine>{{firstname}}</h4>
          <p matLine>Vorname</p>
```

Comment: That breaks again the formatting. When I do this the icon is at the left side right but the firstname and "Vorname" are next to it without any spacing and wrong font-size ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192320/discussion-between-jojofoulk-and-cptdaydreamer).